# Pass value to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I need to get a variable `$option` passed to the php script. the `$option` is on the hidden field named "option".

Basically the user have some items that can be rearranged by using something like drag & drop. The items are stored in an array and once the items had been rearranged, the array gets reordered and saved.

The problem can't be solved by changing `get_option($option);` to `get_option('myoption');` I must get `$option` from the hidden field.

I spend a lot of time searching on the web for an example, solution and tutorial with no hope, It's too much for my head.

```
            array_walk($_POST['order'], 'strip_text_menu_editor');
            $order_array = $_POST['order'];
            $current_menu = get_option($option);    
            $new_order = array();
            foreach($order_array as $order) {
                foreach($current_menu as $key => $value) {
                    if($order == $key) {
                        $new_order[] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
            update_option($option, $new_order);
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" >
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var i = 0';
            echo "jQuery('#sortable li').each(function(){
                    var name = 'listItem_' + i;
                    i++;
                });
            });
            </script>";
            die(true);
```

jQuery

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
                jQuery('#sortable li:odd').addClass('stripe');
                jQuery('#sortable').sortable({
                    handle : '.handle', 
                    update: function(event, ui) {
                        jQuery('#sortable li').removeClass('stripe');
                        jQuery('#sortable li:odd').addClass('stripe');
                        var order = jQuery('#sortable').sortable('toArray');
                        var data = {
                            action: 'menu_editor_special_action',
                            order: order,
                        };
                        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
                            jQuery('#response').html('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li id="listItem_0" class="">Item A</li>
<li id="listItem_1" class="stripe">Item B</li>
<li id="listItem_2" class="">Item C</li>
<li id="listItem_3" class="stripe">Item D</li>
<li id="listItem_4" class="">Item E</li>
<li id="listItem_5" class="stripe">Item F</li>
</ul>
```

Called on the PHP script

```
function strip_text_menu_editor(&$value, $key) {
        $value = str_replace('listItem_', '', $value);
    }
```

Comment: Never render chunks of JS code server side. Never ever.

Comment: Never almost never. ;-) I populate a head.js function with server-side variables in one application. The source variables are in the session, so it makes sense to pass them along. But that's more like collecting resources than "practical executable JS".

Comment: no idea what both of you are talking :(

Comment: @GregPettit `update_option($option, $new_order);` so when the page reload I do `$current_menu = get_option($option);`

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the previous comment you're replying to. Have you taken time to sanity check that what you think you are setting and getting has been gotten and set? In the jQuery you are sending the PHP a data object with order: order in it. Shouldn't the same Ajax call be sending the new "option"? The PHP also doesn't seem to be attempting to grab a new "option" from POST. I think I'm still missing the big picture.

Comment: @GregPettit you are not missing the big picture. I don't know how to grab the `option` because I don't know how to make the same Ajax send the `option` the whole script was working fine before I decide that `option` should be a variable passed from an input field. - Note that can be an hidden input field or a hidden div. I hope I'm clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see of the jQuery fragment you've posted, you would need to add the 'option' value to the data array in your post.

```
var data = {
    action: 'menu_editor_special_action',
    order: order,
    option: $('input[name=option]').val(),  //This part is new
};
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
    jQuery('#response').html('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
```

Of course I don't know what sort of data you have stored in 'option' and I don't know what your get_option() etc. functions are doing with it to know how you need to send it for your server-side code to understand, but this should get you started.

Comment: So on the php to get the value from the input field I should do `$option = $_POST['option'];` ??